# In Django, Can I `defer()` fields in an object that's being queried by `select_related()`

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-select-related

In my Django app I want to use `select_related()` on a `QuerySet` to "follow" a `ForeignKey` field, but I only need to access a few of the fields on the "followed" model instance. Can I use the `defer()` method somehow with my "followed" field.

e.g., if I have...

```
class BarModel(models.Model):
    ...
    blah = models.TextField()

class FooModel(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(BarModel)
    ...
```

...and I'm doing `FooModel.objects.all().select_related('bar')` how can I `defer()` the field `blah`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using Django's double-underscore notation as shown [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#defer).

```
FooModel.objects.all().select_related('bar').defer('bar__blah', ...)
```

Comment: Note: currently there is an opened issue with select_related for o2o relationship and 'only()' method ('defer' works fine). https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23051 (maybe would be useful for somebody)