# Django's double-underscore notation not working here

Tags: python, django

I have combined these two answers: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919031/in-django-can-i-defer-fields-in-an-object-thats-being-queried-by-select-r) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329301/django-rest-framework-define-fields-in-nested-object) In the attempt to select only certain fields from nested objects without any success at all, the result is returning ALL fields from all tables.

serializers:

```
class NameTestTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TestTypeModel
        fields = 'name'

class ExecutedTestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    test_type = NameTestTypeSerializer
    class Meta:
        model = ExecutedTestModel
        fields = ('id',  'result', 'test_type')
        depth = 1
```

models:

```
class TestTypeModel(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=255, unique=True)
    ........
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'TestType'

class ExecutedTestModel(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    test_type = models.ForeignKey(TestTypeModel, to_field='id')
    result = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ExecutedTest'
```

viewset:

```
class ExecutedTestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    serializer_class = ExecutedTestSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = ExecutedTestModel.objects.all().select_related('test_type').defer('test_type__executable' )
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 1):

How did you check that executable is fetched? In django you can access deferred fields, they are loaded from db on demand.

I believe the problem isn't in underscore notation, instead it is in the definition of the serializers.

Comment: I use djnago_rest_framework I can see there the fields that are fetched

Comment: The results in rest framework can contain the executable field's value even if it is deferred in the query. That is, deferring the field in get_queryset() doesn't cause rest framework to exclude that field.

Comment: then how you exclude it